# How could some smart high school kids sabotage a natural gas well?

Tags: climate, near-future

One of my young eco-warriors in a near future climate disaster thriller needs to strike out at a big energy company that pretends to be developing renewables but is actually developing more and more natural gas wells. I don't want the kids to actually hurt anyone, but one of them heads off to sabotage a well in angry moment. Could he put something down the well pipe that would plug it? Sure sounds like it can take tons of cement to plug a well effectively. Could he do something that would damage the well pad heavily enough to put it out of commission for a few weeks? These kids are all about saving the planet, so it would be great if their sabotage options didn't hurt the environment. They aren't going to blow up a pipeline, for example. Well, I did let them blow up an unfinished section of pipeline, but that way I figured they wouldn't cause a spill. This particular character does have a strong background (for his age anyway) in explosives. Another character is a chemistry genius. Is there some way the kids could pollute the fracking fluids on a well and gum it up badly enough to stop production, or does the fracking really just occur right at the start of a natural gas well's life? Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: Questions about the action of a character in a story are not suited for worldbuilding, because they are about your story, not about the rules of your world.

Comment: Is this well being dug, being commissioned, or has it been in production for a while? Once commissioned, gas wells are fairly automated in production. A maintenance crew shows up once in a while. I suppose he could close the valve and then  drop a truckload of cement on top of it.

Comment: How could some smart high school kids sabotage a natural gas well? One method would be to ask how to do it on this site.

Comment: I see this is in the Reopen Queue.  1. There's no worldbuilding here; 2. the question was closed as story based and hasn't been improved to make it not story based, so there is no reason to reopen; 3. the question is a simple real world "how do I accomplish X act of terrorism" query which we don't really entertain here

Comment: Dear OP: Do be careful how you word questions like this!  You don't have any fictional world context and your question reads more like an attempt to learn how to accomplish real world  terrorism. Read our [tour] and [help] and [learn what Worldbuilding is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about)

Comment: Dear elemtilas, I do apologize if I have stepped over the boundaries. I found this site by looking at a question by an author asked here while working on a thriller. He askied how to hypothetically poison an oil field, and he had received several technical, thoughtful and enthusiastic replies. My near future climate thriller about young eco warriors/terrorists is a tricky balancing act and I hope will  make high students ponder how far it is right to go to defend their planet. I shall be more careful how I frame questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Once commissioned, gas wells are fairly automated in production. A maintenance crew shows up once in a while. I suppose he could close the valve and then drop a truckload of cement on top of it.

Comment: A high school kid could get access to a truck load of cement? Must be from a wealthy family.

Comment: @JBH Anyone can buy a truckload of cement, if they can pay for it. Delivery, however, is another issue.

Comment:  That's my point. Have you seen the cost for a truck load of cement lately?

Comment: @ JBH Yep just had a garage floor put in. They did not deliver pre-mix, it was a batch-on-site unit - brings the raw materials in the truck, and the truck mixes it on-site. Maybe the kid has 'friends' that can 'borrow' the truck.

Comment: That's more like it! Teens boost the truck full of cement, go to the automated LP site, close the valve and dump the truck. They don't wash it out just to throw a vulgar hand gesture to the industrialized world (which created the truck....).